# Stuck at a proof with integrals

Tags: real-analysis

If $f :\left[0,1\right]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is integrable and positive with
$$
\int_0^1 f(x) \;dx=1
$$ 
Prove that for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$, there is partition $0=t_0< t_1<\cdots< t_n =1$ such that $\int f(x)\; dx =1/n$ from  $t_k$ to $t_{k+1}$ with $k=0, 1,\cdots,n-1$.

I set $g(x)= \int f(x)\;dx$ from $x$ to $x+1$ because I know $g'(x)>0$ but I don't know if it's helpful.

Comment: Consider the function $F(t) = \int_0^t f(x)\,dx$. That function is continuous.

Comment: I'll just add to Daniel Fischer, consider also the intermediate value theorem.

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel commented $F\left(t\right)=\int_{0}^{t}f\left(x\right)dx$
is a continuous function. This with $F\left(0\right)=0$ and $F\left(1\right)=1$.
Secondly it is monotonically increasing, and applying the intermediate value theorem you can pove that for every
$y_{0}\in\left[0,1\right]$ a unique $x_{0}$ exists with $F\left(x_{0}\right)=y_{0}$.
This together tells us that $F:\left[0,1\right]\rightarrow\left[0,1\right]$
has an inverse $F^{-1}:\left[0,1\right]\rightarrow\left[0,1\right]$

Now define $t_{k}=F^{-1}\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)$.